# How to use [[ repeatIn(o.invoice_line,'l', 'td') ]] : cycle of each line, and for each row of data to create a cell in openerp

Tags: openerp-7, rml

I am creating a new report with RML in OpenERP. Here is my Python function:

```
def get_employee_lines(self, context=None):
    print ('--------------------MOMO----------------------')
    res_list=[]
    payslip_line = self.pool.get('hr.payslip')
    print payslip_line

    obj_ids = payslip_line.search(self.cr, self.uid, [])
    print obj_ids
    for res in payslip_line.read(self.cr, self.uid, obj_ids, ['id', 'employee_id'], context=False):
        print res['employee_id'][1]
        obj = {}
        obj['name'] = res['employee_id'][1]
        res_list.append(obj)
    return res_list
```

and my RML:

```
 <tr>
    <td>
      <para style="P9">NOM EMPLOYÉ</para>
    </td>

    <td>
      <para style="P7">[[ repeatIn(get_employee_lines(), 'o') ]]</para>
      <para style="P7">[[ o['name'] ]]</para>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I want to put each employee in a new cell which means td.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have found it.
 Here is the answer.
First, i had to change the version of my OpenOffice which is v4.1.X.
Second, i used [[ repeatIn(get_employee_lines(example.company_id,example.date_start,example.date_end), 'o', 'td') ]] which Loop on every line and make a new table cell for each line.

So here is the right answer:

```
 <tr>
  <td>
  <para style="P8">NOM EMPLOYÉ</para>
  </td>
  <td>
 <para style="P7">[[      repeatIn(get_employee_lines(example.company_id,example.date_start,example.d      ate_end), 'o', 'td') ]]</para>
 <para style="P7">[[ o['name'] ]]</para>
</td>
</tr>*
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is this:

```
<tr>
    <td> 
        <para style="P9">NOM EMPLOYÉ</para>
    </td>

    <section>
        [[ repeatIn(get_employee_lines(), 'o') ]]
        <td>
            <para style="P7">[[ o['name'] ]]</para>
        </td>
    </section>
</tr>
```

Basically whenever you have repeatIn call you need to put it in or just outside the section, and everything inside section will be repeated. However be careful with  if you use this because that element is usually hard-coded to fixed number of columns (you are generating table after all).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer sir. But, what i want is to repeat colums not rows!!! How can i do that. as i know when i use repeatIn(get_employee_lines(), 'o', 'td') normally it should work but i do that i got an error which is: 2015-09-01 09:56:35,335 5014 ERROR openerp openerp.service.web_services: Exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'
Please help please

Comment: Code I provided should work, for that matter that concept will work every time when you use it regardless what is inside of section. I suggest you check object you are returning.

Comment: Friend what i want to do is to display the result on the horizontal which means make a loop on creating columns. Each result in a colum